# Separate string by N times delimeter

Tags: r

I have character vector separated by `\n`.

```
x <- "Breakdown\nttm\n31/12/2020\n31/12/2019\n31/12/2018\n31/12/2017\nTotal revenue\n7,37,80,000\n7,36,21,000\n7,71,47,000\n7,95,90,000\n7,91,39,000\nCost of revenue\n3,79,22,000\n3,80,46,000\n4,06,59,000\n4,26,55,000\n4,29,13,000\nGross profit\n3,58,57,000\n3,55,75,000\n3,64,88,000\n3,69,36,000\n3,62,27,000"
```

Desired output should be in data frame format. It's fixed - There will be always 6 columns. First 6 values would be header.

[image: Data]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the string on `\n`, use first 6 values as headers and rest of the values as part of the dataframe filling them rowwise.

```
tmp <- unlist(strsplit(x, '\n'))

data.frame(matrix(tail(tmp, -6), ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE, 
           dimnames = list(NULL, head(tmp, 6))), check.names = FALSE)

#        Breakdown         ttm  31/12/2020  31/12/2019  31/12/2018  31/12/2017
#1   Total revenue 7,37,80,000 7,36,21,000 7,71,47,000 7,95,90,000 7,91,39,000
#2 Cost of revenue 3,79,22,000 3,80,46,000 4,06,59,000 4,26,55,000 4,29,13,000
#3    Gross profit 3,58,57,000 3,55,75,000 3,64,88,000 3,69,36,000 3,62,27,000
```

Comment: I'm so sorry dear Ronak as I hadn't refreshed the page so did not notice your solution posted earlier.

Comment: No problem. Happens with all of us :) Also it's not exactly the same so worth keeping.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are always a source of inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the following solution:

```
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(x, "\n", fixed = TRUE)), ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE))
data <- setNames(data[-1, ], data[1, ])
rownames(data) <- seq_len(nrow(data))

        Breakdown         ttm  31/12/2020  31/12/2019  31/12/2018  31/12/2017
1   Total revenue 7,37,80,000 7,36,21,000 7,71,47,000 7,95,90,000 7,91,39,000
2 Cost of revenue 3,79,22,000 3,80,46,000 4,06,59,000 4,26,55,000 4,29,13,000
3    Gross profit 3,58,57,000 3,55,75,000 3,64,88,000 3,69,36,000 3,62,27,000
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do this dynamically in `base R`

```
read.csv(text = gsub("(([^;]+;){6})", "\\1\n", gsub("\n", ";", x)),
      sep=";", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)[, 1:6]
```

-outut

```
        Breakdown         ttm  31/12/2020  31/12/2019  31/12/2018  31/12/2017
1   Total revenue 7,37,80,000 7,36,21,000 7,71,47,000 7,95,90,000 7,91,39,000
2 Cost of revenue 3,79,22,000 3,80,46,000 4,06,59,000 4,26,55,000 4,29,13,000
3    Gross profit 3,58,57,000 3,55,75,000 3,64,88,000 3,69,36,000 3,62,27,000
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way

```r
x <- "Breakdown\nttm\n31/12/2020\n31/12/2019\n31/12/2018\n31/12/2017\nTotal revenue\n7,37,80,000\n7,36,21,000\n7,71,47,000\n7,95,90,000\n7,91,39,000\nCost of revenue\n3,79,22,000\n3,80,46,000\n4,06,59,000\n4,26,55,000\n4,29,13,000\nGross profit\n3,58,57,000\n3,55,75,000\n3,64,88,000\n3,69,36,000\n3,62,27,000"
library(tidyverse)
x %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  set_names('X') %>%
  separate_rows(X, sep = '\n') %>%
  mutate(d =  1+ ((row_number()-1) %% 6),
         d = paste0('V', d)) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = X, names_from = d, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(everything())
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   V1              V2          V3          V4          V5          V6         
#>   <chr>           <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
#> 1 Breakdown       ttm         31/12/2020  31/12/2019  31/12/2018  31/12/2017 
#> 2 Total revenue   7,37,80,000 7,36,21,000 7,71,47,000 7,95,90,000 7,91,39,000
#> 3 Cost of revenue 3,79,22,000 3,80,46,000 4,06,59,000 4,26,55,000 4,29,13,000
#> 4 Gross profit    3,58,57,000 3,55,75,000 3,64,88,000 3,69,36,000 3,62,27,000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>